# ImportError: No module named QtCore

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, qt, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my robot model as a URDF file and when I launch it in a launch file to display it in Rviz, I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/****/first_workspace/src/robot_model/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 6, in <module>
from python_qt_binding.QtCore import Qt

ImportError: No module named QtCore

[joint_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 44456, exit code 1, cmd /home/****/first_workspace/src/robot_model/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/****/.ros/log/8bb4a410-324b-11e6-812c-480fcf447f3c/joint_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/***/.ros/log/8bb4a410-324b-11e6-812c-480fcf447f3c/joint_state_publisher-2*.log
```

What could be the issue here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236952/importerror:-no-module-named-qtcore/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
Please explain why you have a clone of the `robot_model` source repository in your workspace.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-06-16**:
When I checked for the package dependency of `robot_model` , it was not satisfied. So I decided to clone it in my workspace and try to satisfy all the dependencies. Is that a wrong method?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-16**:
It depends: by default, you'll want to install *binary* packages. On Ubuntu, those are installed using `apt-get` or the Software Centre. Only if you want to develop the package your installing, or are running a system for which no binaries exist, you compile from source.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-16**:
As to how to then satisfy dependencies (for packages you created yourself, or cloned from someone else): run `rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` (after you have `source`d the appropriate `setup.bash`). That installs all dependencies for you.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-06-16**:
How do I use `apt-get` to install binary ROS packages in the root directory?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-16**:
What is the "root directory"? `apt-get` will *always* install packages system-wide. The fact that you run `rosdep install ..` and point it to your catkin workspace has nothing to do with where it installs packages.

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-06-16**:
I did the `rosdep install ..` and all the dependencies were satisfied. But the error still persists. What could be the issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-16**:
Have you removed all the `robot_model` packages from your `catkin_ws/src` directory? If you are not planning on working on `robot_model` or any of its packages, remove it from your workspace. Then run `rosdep install ..`  again. Then remove your `devel` and `build` folder and rebuild your ws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last comment of gvdhoorn was the solution. I removed `robot_model` packages and ran `rosdep install ..` and then removed the `devel` and `build` folders and ran `catkin_make`. That did the trick.

---

Originally posted by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) with karma: 95 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0